# Basic fading slideshow

Tags: image, button, text, slideshow

I´m trying to implement in my website a basic fading slideshow. This is already done but my question is how can I do a slideshow with images, text and one button? Like this for example:

http://www.wds.co/

I used for my slideshow Cycle2 Plugin is easy to implement and to getting started.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be acheived by some basic jquery code.

Do some workarround and learn jquery (code sample on : http://jqueryui.com/effect/)

Good luck!!!

Comment: I have updated an existing JSFiddle.

This is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/2kkHH/630/


But the thing is if can I control the time of the "drop" effect? 
In the other website (wds.co) the text appear and disappear better than my JSFiddle. How I can get it?

Comment: You can do better:
fadeOut(2000), fadeIn(2000) respectively.

Does this answer your question?
If so, please mark it as an answer.

Thanks :)

Comment: Also, you can go to http://www.wds.co/, open it on chrome, and choose: tools -> tools for developers, and see the code behind, including which jquery.
I see site use: jquery-easing-1.3.js, jquery-nicescroll.js, jquery.prettyphoto.
Maybe you find that help ...